# Getting (mobile) device name from javascript

Tags: javascript, mobile-website

Is there a way to get the name of a mobile device (e.g. "John's iPhone" ) using javascript?

---

Maybe I wasn't very clear... what I meant is not whether it's an iPhone, iPad etc. but the "device name" - for example it can be "John's iPhone".

Comment: depends on which browser the mobile device is running but do you want to know if it is an iphone or android device or which name exactly do you need ?

Comment: The only thing you can get is User-Agent

Comment: Here is a link to use `WURFL.js`, it's free http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/07/01/server-side-device-detection-with-javascript/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can't do this through javascript for a web app running in a native browser - javascript generally doesn't have access to this personal identifying data.

One possible way is to use a framework like [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) which may have an API to access the device name. But then, you can only deploy your web site via an app store, so this could be very limiting based on your use case.

Answer (score 13):

Your best bet is to use the user agent:

e.g.

```
const ua = navigator.userAgent
const device = {
  iPad: /iPad/.test(ua),
  iPhone: /iPhone/.test(ua),
  Android4: /Android 4/.test(ua)
}
```

The object will allow you to write nice conditional logic such as `if(device.iPad) { /* do stuff */ }`

Answer (score 2):

I'm working with mobile device with embedded scanner.  To be able to use some the JavaScript library of different devices and to avoid conflict with those libraries of different manufacturer (Zebra, Honeywell, Datalogic, iOs ect...) I need to come up with a way to identify each devices so I can load the proper library and this is what I came up with.  Enjoy

```
getDeviceName: function () {
    var deviceName = '';

    var isMobile = {
        Android: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
        },
        Datalogic: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/DL-AXIS/i);
        },
        Bluebird: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/EF500/i);
        },
        Honeywell: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/CT50/i);
        },
        Zebra: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/TC70|TC55/i);
        },
        BlackBerry: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
        },
        iOS: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
        },
        Windows: function() {
            return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
        },
        any: function() {
            return (isMobile.Datalogic() || isMobile.Bluebird() || isMobile.Honeywell() || isMobile.Zebra() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.Android() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Windows());
        }
    };

    if (isMobile.Datalogic())
        deviceName = 'Datalogic';
    else if (isMobile.Bluebird())
        deviceName = 'Bluebird';
    else if (isMobile.Honeywell())
        deviceName = 'Honeywell';
    else if (isMobile.Zebra())
        deviceName = 'Zebra';
    else if (isMobile.BlackBerry())
        deviceName = 'BlackBerry';
    else if (isMobile.iOS())
        deviceName = 'iOS';
    else if ((deviceName == '') && (isMobile.Android()))
        deviceName = 'Android';
    else if ((deviceName == '') && (isMobile.Windows()))
        deviceName = 'Windows';

    if (deviceName != '') {
        consoleLog('Devices information deviceName = ' + deviceName);
        consoleLog('Devices information any = ' + isMobile.any());
        consoleLog('navigator.userAgent = ' + navigator.userAgent);
    }

    return deviceName;
},
```

and this is an example of how it can be used:

```
initializeHandheldScanners: function () {
    if (DeviceCtrl.getDeviceName() == 'Zebra')
        DeviceCtrl.initializeSymbolScanner();

    if (DeviceCtrl.getDeviceName() == 'Honeywell')
        DeviceCtrl.initializeHoneywellScanner();

    if (DeviceCtrl.getDeviceName() == 'Datalogic')
        DeviceCtrl.initializeDatalogicScanner();
},
```

You can say thanks to Cory LaViska.  I did this based on his work.  Here is the link if you want to know more

https://www.abeautifulsite.net/detecting-mobile-devices-with-javascript

Answer (score 2):

You can use this snippet:

```js
const getUA = () => {
    let device = "Unknown";
    const ua = {
        "Generic Linux": /Linux/i,
        "Android": /Android/i,
        "BlackBerry": /BlackBerry/i,
        "Bluebird": /EF500/i,
        "Chrome OS": /CrOS/i,
        "Datalogic": /DL-AXIS/i,
        "Honeywell": /CT50/i,
        "iPad": /iPad/i,
        "iPhone": /iPhone/i,
        "iPod": /iPod/i,
        "macOS": /Macintosh/i,
        "Windows": /IEMobile|Windows/i,
        "Zebra": /TC70|TC55/i,
    }
    Object.keys(ua).map(v => navigator.userAgent.match(ua[v]) && (device = v));
    return device;
}

console.log(getUA());
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript `navigator` object is used for browser detection, it can be used to get browser information such as `appName`, `appCodeName`, `userAgent`, etc. Here we are using the property userAgent, it will return a string from which we can find the match for different devices like `iPhone`, `Windows` etc., and storing in another object named `device`. By looping through the object we can check the property which will be true, will be printed on page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Device</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        const UserAgent = navigator.userAgent
        const device = {
            iPad: /iPad/.test(UserAgent),
            iPhone: /iPhone/.test(UserAgent),
            Android: /Android/.test(UserAgent),
            windows: /Windows/.test(UserAgent)
        }

        for(dev in device){
            if(device[dev])
            document.writeln("You are using " + dev);
        }
        
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

It may help you out to identify user's device :-)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve the mobile device name, you can use the following code snippet:

```
navigator.userAgentData
      .getHighEntropyValues([
        "architecture",
        "model",
        "platform",
        "platformVersion",
        "fullVersionList"
      ])
      .then((ua) => {
        const model = ua["model"];
        if (model) console.log("Phone: " + model);
      });
```

Please note that this code snippet will only work on **Android** devices.

Here are some example device names that you might get as output:

- Phone: POCO F1
- Phone: PIXEL 5
- Phone: SM-G955U

You can find an example implementation of this code [here](https://c01wt9.csb.app/).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34566684)

Comment: This is actually helpful for Android phones.