# How can I get the user’s PC name using JavaScript in the browser?

Tags: javascript, client-side

How can I show a user his PC name, on the client side?

I’m working with Jade and Express on the server side. I need to allow the user to select an option to get data from a local service.

Comment: Although it specifies mobile devices, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930356/getting-mobile-device-name-from-javascript) might be asking the same thing. (If so, sadly the answer is “You can’t”.)

Comment: You can get the username, though - so if you're trying to identify someone on a domain network, that might be good enough.