# Device Info Details using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I want to get hardware details of a mobile device using Jquery or Javascript. Please tell me is there a script or a way to to achieve device information via this or any extension that helps this way. Thank you.

Comment: Which particular HW details are you interested in? WebGL capabilities? RAM? CPU?

Comment: RAM and CPU particularly I want.

Comment: Don't think that's possible. You may be able to get the number of CPU cores using [this](https://github.com/oftn/core-estimator)

Answer (score 0):

if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 // some code..
}

or

$.browser.device = (/android|webos|iphone|ipad|ipod|blackberry|iemobile|opera mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));

Check below links.

- [Getting device name and model using javascript, jquery or php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29048494/getting-device-name-and-model-using-javascript-jquery-or-php)
- http://www.sitepoint.com/detect-mobile-devices-jquery/