# How to fetch the device information using Angular2 and Typescript

Tags: windows, angular, typescript, navigator

I have a table, I need to fill these details into my table from typescript.

```
1.Device Name
2. Device OS
3. Location
4. Browser
5. IsActive
```

These fields must be filled from typescript, so can anyone help me to solve this

Comment: [Device name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930356/getting-mobile-device-name-from-javascript), [device OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514179/how-to-find-the-operating-system-version-using-javascript), [location](https://www.w3schools.com/Html/html5_geolocation.asp), [browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser/9851769) and I don't know the last one. But seriously, make some research before asking.

Comment: @trichetriche i had also been through that question but it doesnt help, and IsActive means, it must say whether device is active or nott

Comment: "That question" ? I gave you four questions that explain everything you can and can't do. If it doesn't help you, nothing will.

Comment: please try this https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-device-detector

Comment: and also you can get this detail from api call and in c# you will get all infrormation then store in table that is easy way

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use, **`ngx-device-detector`**

> `ngx-device-detector` is An `Angular 2` (and beyond) powered AOT
>   compatible device detector that helps to identify browser, os and
>   other useful information regarding the device using the app. The
>   processing is based on user-agent.

**Installation:**

To install this library, run:

```
$ npm install ngx-device-detector --save
```

**Usage:**

```
Import DeviceDetectorModule in your app.module.ts

  import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
  import { DeviceDetectorModule } from 'ngx-device-detector';
  ...
  @NgModule({
    declarations: [
      ...
      LoginComponent,
      SignupComponent
      ...
    ],
    imports: [
      CommonModule,
      FormsModule,
      DeviceDetectorModule.forRoot()
    ],
    providers:[
      AuthService
    ]
    ...
  })
```

**In your component where you want to use the Device Service**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
  ...
  import { DeviceDetectorService } from 'ngx-device-detector';
  ...
  @Component({
    selector: 'home',  // <home></home>
    styleUrls: [ './home.component.scss' ],
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    ...
  })

  export class HomeComponent {
    deviceInfo = null;
    ...
    constructor(..., private http: Http, private deviceService: DeviceDetectorService) {
      this.epicFunction();
    }
    ...
    epicFunction() {
      console.log('hello `Home` component');
      this.deviceInfo = this.deviceService.getDeviceInfo();
      console.log(this.deviceInfo);
    }
    ...
  }
```

**Device service:**

Holds the following properties:

- browser
- os
- device
- userAgent
- os_version

Comment: Hi, I am getting this error after using the DeviceDetectorModule "./node_modules/ngx-device-detector/fesm2015/ngx-device-detector.mjs 813:30-36
Can't import the named export 'Inject' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)"

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[angular-device-information](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-device-information/v/4.0.0)** is a powerful angular package to detect operating system and version

> `npm i angular-device-information`

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 ...
 import { AngularDeviceInformationService } from 'angular-device-information';
 ...
 @Component({
   selector: 'home',  // <home></home>
   styleUrls: [ './home.component.scss' ],
   templateUrl: './home.component.html',
   ...
 })

 export class HomeComponent {
 
   constructor(private deviceInformationService: AngularDeviceInformationService) {
 
      console.log(deviceInformationService.isMobile());  // returns if the device is a mobile device (android / iPhone / windows-phone etc)
      console.log(deviceInformationService.isTablet());  // returns if the device is a tablet (tablet iPad etc)
      console.log(deviceInformationService.isDesktop()); // returns if the app is running on a Desktop browser.
      console.log(deviceInformationService.getDeviceType()); // returns if the app is running on a Desktop browser.
      console.log(deviceInformationService.getDeviceInfo().os);  // returns os name like Windows/Andtoid/iOS/Linux/Mac OS X etc
      console.log(deviceInformationService.getDeviceInfo().osVersion);  // returns os version like 10/8.1/7 ...etc
      console.log(deviceInformationService.getDeviceInfo().browser);  // returns browser name like chrome/firefox ...etc
      console.log(deviceInformationService.getDeviceInfo().browserVersion);  // returns browser version as number
      console.log(deviceInformationService.getDeviceInfo().browserMajorVersion);  // returns full browser version as number
      console.log(deviceInformationService.getDeviceInfo().screen_resolution);  // returns screnn size like 1390x860/640x800 ...etc
      console.log(deviceInformationService.getDeviceInfo().cookies);  // returns cookies enabled or no 
      console.log(deviceInformationService.getDeviceInfo().userAgent);  // returns userAgent
   }
   
 }
```