# How to fetch the device name from the browser using angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a grid list, where in it gets filled with User device details as soon as the user is logged in.
so can anyone help me how do i fetch the device name from the browser and also i need to fetch the location of the system.

This is the [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dedrza?file=src/app/app.component.ts) of my code.

Ts:

```
 var isDeviceType = (/iPad/i).test(navigator.userAgent) ?
    "iOS" : (/iPhone/i).test(navigator.userAgent) ?
    "iOS" : (/Android/i).test(navigator.userAgent) ?
    "Android" : (/BlackBerry/i).test(navigator.userAgent) ?
    "BlackBerry" : "Browser";
  console.log(isDeviceType)
  this.isDeviceType = isDeviceType;
```

From this set of information i am able to get on which i am using my device like `Browser` but i need to fetch the name of device and i am using `navigator.userAgent` to detect browser

Comment: for me your condition is working, and I m getting `browser` in console

Comment: @Sravan ya browser is fine, but i need to fetch name of the device

Comment: from your code, I can see that the browser name is cmng correct for me, in `chrome` and it is showing `chrome`

Comment: browser name is also correct, i need the device name

Comment: in which device you are checking?

Comment: i am checking on chrome, but i need the name if the device inside chrome

Comment: I didn't understand, what is device?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11930356

Comment: @Sravan i need to fetch the client machine name, any idea please help

Answer (score 0):

From Javascript, you can only get user agent, not the device details.
If you use a framework like phonegap it has API to fetch device details.

Ref:
[Getting (mobile) device name from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930356/getting-mobile-device-name-from-javascript?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)